# How to use SQLite in Background Task

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Since WinRT will lock the screen after a while if no user interaction, so I use background task. I need to update tables in SQLite while connecting to Webservices.

Not sure where to begin after creating a BackgroundTask project. Need some help like connecting to SQLite and Insert and Update functions. Thanks

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

namespace BackgroundTaskProject
{

    //
    // A background task always implements the IBackgroundTask interface.
    //

    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        //
        // The Run method is the entry point of a background task.
        //
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For how to implement a BackgroundTask I wrote a blogpost about it a while ago:
http://www.pazquality.com/post/2013/02/20/WinRT-BackgroundTasks.aspx

For SQLite code example for WIN 8 RT, I would suggest to take a look at the code on MSDN:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-For-Windows-8-Metro-2ec7a882